# Adding axis to offset contour plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

In an offset contour plot (like on the left in the image below):

[image: Example of offset contour plot]

I have been trying to add horizontal and vertical axis in the X-Z and Y-Z planes over the offset contour plots (like in the right image). Notice that the horizontal & vertical axis go all the way out to the xlim, ylim & zlim extents and dont stop at the end of the main data plot.

Many of you will recognize this demo as the [matplotlib3d contour3d_demo3](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo3.html). My code for now is the exact same.

The bit of code for plotting the offset 2D contour plot in the Y-Z plane is:

```
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

In 2D plots I would just use `axhline(0, color='black')`. Unfortunately axhline/axvline don't have an offset option that functions like the ax.contour does as far as I can tell.  I can kind of get what I'm looking for playing tricks like zeroing out the Z data to get a horizontal line:

```
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, 0*Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

But the problem is that the line stops at the edge of the data. I want to be able to arbitrarily set my xlim, ylim & zlim and get horizontal & vertical axis that span those ranges. Any ideas on a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, just draw them yourself! Adapting the code from the example, add the following lines:

```
import numpy as np
XL = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)
YL = np.linspace(Y.min(),Y.max(),100)
ZL = np.linspace(Z.min(),Z.max(),100)

ax.plot(XL,0*XL,-100,zdir='z',color='k',lw=5)
ax.plot(0*YL,YL,-100,zdir='z',color='k',lw=5)

ax.plot(YL,0*YL,-40,zdir='x',color='k',lw=5)
ax.plot(0*ZL,ZL,-40,zdir='x',color='k',lw=5)

ax.plot(XL,0*XL,40,zdir='y',color='k',lw=5)
ax.plot(0*ZL,ZL,40,zdir='y',color='k',lw=5)
```

[image]

The trick is that `ax.plot` in 3D has extra arguments:

```
plot(self, xs, ys, *args, **kwargs) method of matplotlib.axes.Axes3DSubplot instance
    Plot 2D or 3D data.

    ==========  ================================================
    Argument    Description
    ==========  ================================================
    *xs*, *ys*  X, y coordinates of vertices
    *zs*        z value(s), either one for all points or one for each point.
    *zdir*      Which direction to use as z ('x', 'y' or 'z') when plotting a 2D set.
    ==========  ================================================

    Other arguments are passed on to
    :func:`~matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`
```

Comment: Awesome! I did not pick up on the zs values in ax.plot before. I think I get it now. I made your X.min(), etc values match my set_xlim(), etc values and it now gives exactly what I was looking for with the axis going all the way to the edges. Thank you!